# dynamically render selectbox values returned from controller as json

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm seding ajax request which sends some id. Based on that id
i'm querying data and return back to the view as json.
Those data is used to populate selectbox inside view.

I have working example  which receives list of strings which I use to 
populate select box, but I want together with those string and it's id values, so I can be able
 to render inside select box string and it's id.
how can I do that.

This is what I use right now

```
public JsonResult GetKeywords(int id) 
{
    List<string> data = new List<string>();
    var dataKeywords = db.KeyWords.Where(x => x.id == id).ToList();            
    foreach (var item in dataKeywords)
    {
        data.Add(item.Title);                
        // how to pass id?
    }
    return Json(data);
}
```

on the view

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    ...
    options.success = function (dataList) {
        $("#myKeywords").empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < dataList.length; i++) {
            $("#myKeywords").append("<option>" + dataList[i] + "</option>");
        }
        $("#myKeywords").prop("disabled", false);
    };
 });
```

Comment: Did you want the ID to use for the `value` attribute of each option?

Comment: yes, for each data in option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a collection of anonymous objects as json

```
var dataKeywords = db.KeyWords.Where(x => x.id == id).Select(x => new
{
  ID = x.id,
  Text = x.Title
};
return Json(dataKeywords); // JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet?
```

and in the script

```
options.success = function(dataList) {
  $.each(dataList, function(index, item) {
    $("#myKeywords").append($('<option></option>').val(item.ID).text(item.Text));
  });
  ....
```